# Problema de atributo id en json

Tags: javascript, laravel, json

Una tabla de mi base de datos tiene su columna id, la cual en un principio era int, un ejemplo del id que guardaba: 101, pero ahora la cambie a varchar, ejemplo: '1-1-101', en el momento en que uso el método get() de laravel para volver la colección en JSON, el campo trabaja como si fuera int (en caso del ejemplo anterior, retorna 1, cuando debería retornar "1-1-101")

[image: Base de datos con id 1-1-101]

[image: JSON que me retorna int 1]

Comment: ya cambiaste en tu modelo de laravel el tipo de dato que representa el id?

Comment: Asi es, en todo lado he especificado que es string, pero el json retorna int

Comment: La columna de id es tu llave primaria ?

Comment: Asi es, es la llave primaria de mi tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puede estar sucediendo es que Laravel al tomar como convención de que la tabla debe tener una columna llamada id, de tipo entero y auto-incrementable; por defecto puede estar convirtiéndolo a entero. Deberías entonces configurar el modelo para que esta convención no aplique para el mismo. Adicionar estas lineas a tu modelo podría solucionarlo

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id'; //Nombre de la columna que es tu llave primaria por si hay futuros cambios en su nombre
public $incrementing = false; //Deshabilitar de que sea auto-incremental
protected $keyType = 'string'; //Definir de que su tipo de dato es string
```